# Aplicação RMI funciona localhost, mas dá erro ao colocar IP do Servidor

Tags: java, rmi

Se eu executar o trecho do código como está abaixo na minha aplicação, funciona:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    try {
       final InterfaceTrilha interfaceServer = (InterfaceTrilha) Naming.lookup("//localhost:1070/ServidorTrilha");
```

Mas, se eu troco o `localhost` pelo IP da máquina onde se encontra o servidor, como abaixo:

```
final InterfaceTrilha interfaceServer = (InterfaceTrilha) Naming.lookup("//rmi://192.168.0.107/ServidorTrilha");
```

Retorna o seguinte erro:

> ```
> java Cliente
> java.rmi.UnknownHostException: Unknown host: rmi; nested exception is:
>     java.net.UnknownHostException: rmi
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:616)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
>     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
>     at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
>     at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
>     at Cliente.main(Cliente.java:67)
> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: rmi
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
>     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
>     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
>     ... 6 more
> ```

Código do servidor:

```
public Servidor() throws RemoteException{
    try{
        server = new Trilha();
        registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1070);
        registry.rebind("ServidorTrilha", server);
        System.out.println("SERVIDOR REGISTRADO COM SUCESSO!")
```

Vi um problema parecido nessa pergunta: [Java Rmi UnknownHostException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370912/java-rmi-unknownhostexception).

Tentei executar o servidor conforme o desse post, mas mesmo assim ao executar o meu cliente dá este erro `UnknownHostException`.

Comment: Não tem que colocar a porta quando procura pelo servidor também? `final InterfaceTrilha interfaceServer = (InterfaceTrilha) Naming.lookup("//rmi://192.168.0.107:[porta]/ServidorTrilha");`

Comment: Pergunta relacionada (não é duplicata): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175241/132

Comment: Que eu saiba mão tem essa `//` da frente do protocolo, isso é, sua url de lookup deve ser `rmi://host:[porta]/referenciaRemota`. Além disso você precisará preparar o campo do lado do servidor dando permissões para acesso, setando o `java.rmi.server.hostname` (o padrão é 127.0.0.1),etc, para mais detalhes [veja essa resposta do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35855183/664577). Garanta também que a porta 1070 do servidor é alcançavel do lado do cliente quando você levanta o servidor, um firewall pode estar no caminho.

Comment: igorventurelli já tentei também e dá o mesmo erro

Comment: Anthony Accioly deu certo da forma que você falou.
Vlw cara.

Comment: Olá ADR, foi só a URL de lookup ou você fez algo mais? (Vou transformar o comentário em resposta)

Comment: só a URL msmo, já tinha tentando de várias formas.. da forma q vc disse funcionou.. ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Não é necessário usar "//" na frente da declaracao do protocolo rmi.

Na URL do lookup: `Naming.lookup("//rmi://192.168.0.107/ServidorTrilha");`

O correto seria: `Naming.lookup("rmi://192.168.0.107:1070/ServidorTrilha");`